# Book about superhumans hiding among normal humans

Tags: story-identification, books

I think the novel or long short story was published in the last 10 years. It starts with a man who is killed in a car accident. A doctor autopsies him and finds out he is not human, that he is built to live longer than a normal human.

Before the doctor can make his findings public he is mentally herded by someone into dying in an accident.

The rest of the book involves a normal human who gets involved somehow. He even finds out he is married to a superhuman.

Good stuff about the relationships of the super humans with their human cousins.

Answer (score 9):

This sounds like the 1999 Frank Robinson novel [Waiting](https://www.enotes.com/topics/waiting-frank-m-robinson).  Points that match

> I think the novel or long short story was published in the last 10 years.

**Partial Match**:  This was from 1999, so a bit farther back than indicated, but still relatively recent.

> It starts with a man who is killed in a car accident. A doctor autopsies him and finds out he is not human, that he is built to live longer than a normal human.

**Match**:  A man dies in the car and effectively rips the steering wheel off.  Without too many spoilers, the man that dies in the car accident is not truly 'human'

> Before the doctor can make his findings public he is mentally herded by someone into dying in an accident.

**Match**:   A doctor dies under seemingly impossible circumstances just as he is set to deliver a lecture to a circle of old friends....he learns that the doctor had compiled evidence <>.. and was killed to suppress it.

> The rest of the book involves a normal human who gets involved somehow. He even finds out he is married to a superhuman.

**Match**:  One member, television producer Arthur Banks, sets out to uncover the killer.

Comment: Sort of on topic. There were quite a few similarities in the television show; Prey (1998), starring Debra Messing with Robinson's Waiting

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I look forward to re-reading “waiting” and checking out the tv series.